# Logo on iOS sidebar is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

Using the latest version of the iOS app the logo for the main site in the side bar is too big.

[image]

Compare the size of Puzzling vs Meta.Puzzling with the size of Math vs Meta.Math.

<sub><sup>I'm not sure if this is a bug with the iOS app or with the design so I'm posting this here for now.</sup></sub>

---

Edit: I can't seem to reproduce this anymore, it's possible it's been fixed already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed on the server and is just waiting on various levels of cache expiration.